# Python List of Lists Merging/removing duplicates

Tags: python

I've got a list of lists with differing properties:

`list = [['jake', '100', 'science'], ['sam', '200', 'math'], ['jake', '100', 'science'], ['sam', '200', 'science']]`

the list represents students' names, test scores, and subject respectively.

This is the desired output:
`list = [['jake', '200', 'science'], ['sam', '200', 'math'], ['sam', '200', 'science']]`

The scores for Jake's two science scores were added together (100+100 = 200) and list duplicate was removed.

I want to add test scores belonging to the same person and same subject and keep the others separate. Any idea how I can do this seamlessly?

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Quoting @ScottHunter, and also, a list/tuple for holding objects (like `['jake', '200', 'science']`), is not the best answer. Try using classes or dataclasses.

Comment: Additionally, do not use list as a variable name as it is a built-in constructor for lists. if you truly need to name something the same as a built-in append an underscore: e.g. list_ (https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from `itertools` to solve this nicely.

You'll need to both sort and group using the key `lambda x: (x[0], x[2])` which makes sure the sorting and grouping is done by student & subject.

```py
from itertools import groupby
list = [
    ['jake', '100', 'science'],
    ['sam', '200', 'math'],
    ['jake', '100', 'science'],
    ['sam', '200', 'science']
]

sorted_list = sorted(list, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))
grouped_list = groupby(sorted_list, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))

output_list = [[student, str(sum(int(score[1]) for score in scores)), subject]
    for (student, subject), scores in grouped_list]
```

Gives as desired:

```
[['jake', '200', 'science'], ['sam', '200', 'math'], ['sam', '200', 'science']]
```

Comment: I like this answer using groupby as this feels like a student looking for help in basic python and not wanting an answer such as "use classes" or "use pandas". I would adjust the output to build the list they were looking to create instead of printing though. e.g. instead of print: `output_list = [[ss[0], str(sum(int(score[1]) for score in scores), ss[1]] for ss, scores in grouped_list]`

Comment: Corrected syntax from my comment above: `output_list = [[ss[0], str(sum(int(score[1]) for score in scores)), ss[1]] for ss, scores in grouped_list]`

Comment: Good point @clesiemo3, I've edited my answer to include your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Something along the lines of

```py
from functools import reduce

list = [['jake', '100', 'science'], ['sam', '200', 'math'], ['jake', '100', 'science'], ['sam', '200', 'science']]


def reducer(acc, item):
    key = f'{item[0]}_{item[2]}'
    if key not in acc:
        item[1] = int(item[1])
        acc[key] = item
    else:
        acc[key][1] = acc[key][1] + int(item[1])

    return acc

new_list = reduce(reducer, list, {}).values()


print(new_list)
```